# Area Chart Change the Default Colors

Tags: java, css, charts, javafx

i want to change the default colors of the Area Chart. I have more or less a chart like this:

[image]
Here you can see that there are 3 lines in the chart. Every chart has a Fill-Color and the Line-Color. How can i change this 2 things?

I checked the CSS in the Scene Builder but i don't know how i can change the colors.
I think it must be something like this:

> .default-color0: red;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css styling applied to a chart is defined in the modena.css file. If you want to modify some properties, look for the style class and change some value.

These are the default properties for the first three series (regarding the symbol, line and fill for each series):

```
.chart-area-symbol {
    -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_1, white;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 4px; /* makes sure this remains circular */
    -fx-padding: 3px;
}
.default-color0.chart-area-symbol { -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_1, white; }
.default-color1.chart-area-symbol { -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_2, white; }
.default-color2.chart-area-symbol { -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_3, white; }
.chart-series-area-line {
    -fx-stroke: CHART_COLOR_1;
    -fx-stroke-width: 1px;
}
.default-color0.chart-series-area-line { -fx-stroke: CHART_COLOR_1; }
.default-color1.chart-series-area-line { -fx-stroke: CHART_COLOR_2; }
.default-color2.chart-series-area-line { -fx-stroke: CHART_COLOR_3; }
.chart-series-area-fill {
    -fx-stroke: null;
    -fx-fill: CHART_COLOR_1_TRANS_20;
}
.default-color0.chart-series-area-fill { -fx-fill: CHART_COLOR_1_TRANS_20; }
.default-color1.chart-series-area-fill { -fx-fill: CHART_COLOR_2_TRANS_20; }
.default-color2.chart-series-area-fill { -fx-fill: CHART_COLOR_3_TRANS_20; }
```

So you just need to provide your custom colors.

Comment: Is there a possibilty to change the opacity also ?

Comment: Sure, just provide the alpha channel too. The default fill values already have 20% opacity: `CHART_COLOR_1_TRANS_20: #f3622d33`.

Comment: Perada, i have a Hex-Color Value like #007FC3 -> Now i want to change there the opacity, how can i do that?

Comment: The opacity can be set easily with two more digits for the alpha channel: #007FC3FF means opacity 100%, #007Fc37F means 50%, #007FC300 gives 0%...